# Binding button disable property to treeview selection in fxml

Tags: java, binding, javafx, fxml

I can't find any example of simple binding in fxml only.

I want to enable/disable button if an item is selected on a tree view.

I have tried this code (labels are used for testing bindings):

```xml
<Scene xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <BorderPane>
    <top>
      <Button text="test" disable="${treeView.selectionModel.selectedItem.isNull}" />
    </top>
    <center>
      <TreeView fx:id="treeView" />
    </center>
    <bottom>
      <Label text="${treeView.selectionModel}" />
      <Label text="${treeView.selectionModel.selectedItem.isNull}" />
    </bottom>
  </BorderPane>
</Scene>
```

This code produce no errors.

The first label displays treeView's selection model `toString()`.
The second label displays nothing, but should display true or false.
The button should enable and disable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

From code you can do something like this:

```
treeview.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
    {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue)
        {
            if (newValue.intValue() > 0)
                button.setDisable(true);
            else
                button.setDisable(false);
        }
});
```